# How is Vatan's sister publicly lesbian?

Tags: plot-explanation, allied

In the movie [***Allied***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3640424/), Brad Pitt's character has a lesbian sister who publicly displays her sexual orientation. As being gay was somewhat a taboo at the time in the U.K, or virtually anywhere else on earth, wouldn't it have been dangerous for her to behave so particularly in the highly disciplined environment of the RAF?

Mathematical genius and codebreaker Alan Turing also got into serious trouble when he was found to be gay years after the war which eventually lead to him apparently committing a suicide, so I think something is out of place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Wouldn't it have been dangerous for her to behave so particularly in the highly disciplined environment of the RAF?

Only in that lesbianism would have been seen as "not normal" (thus taboo as you note) which might have negative social consequences but **lesbianism is not now, nor has it ever been, illegal in the UK.**

The same is not true of, in the case of Turing, **male homosexuality** which remained illegal until c.1967 when the Sexual Offences Act (1967) was passed with the age of consent being (then) 21.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. To me, it just doesn't make sense that it was legal to be lesbian but illegal to be gay.

Comment: British laws....this one dated back to 1885 (if not earlier)...something to do with *penetration*.....anal sex of any kind was also illegal.

Comment: See Section 11 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criminal_Law_Amendment_Act_1885#Section_11

Comment: Not about the law. It's about how lesbian activity fascinates men. Regardless of the era and clearly how unbuttoned the RAF are during off-hours, "lesbian action" excites.

Answer (score 3):

Lesbianism is generally considered to be "titillating" to heterosexual men, as demonstrated by the two soldiers who ask Max's sister to kiss her girlfriend while they watch. This is the subtext of this character portrayal.
 [image: Louise kisses Bridget]

Conversely, male homosexuality can be perceived as 
"[threatening](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2936486/)."

Given it's war time with death and danger integrated into daily life, social mores are dramatically relaxed.  Bridget Vatan makes casual mention of this "freedom" during dinner.

[image: Bridget &Louise]

Comment: Great link! ought to read it when I get some free time.